# Same code working differently on different userforms

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a userform for recording and retrieving data about engines being tested. For one type of engine the code is working fine, for another I'm getting a problem. The only difference between the two is the name of the page where the data is stored, for the working one it's DW10 data and for the non working one it's XUD9 data. It will write to the XUD9 data and retrieve from it with no problem but it won't allow me to update it so it can't be the name of the sheet as none of the userform would work.

The XUD9 userform is exactly the same as the DW10 one, it's a copy with just the name references changed.

```
Private Sub confirmupdate_Click()

Dim Rerow As Range

Set Rerow = Worksheets("DW10 Data").Range("H:H").Find(Codetext, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)


Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 2).Value = Rigtext2.Text
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 4).Value = Serialtext2.Text
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 5).Value = Hourstext2.Text
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 3).Value = CDbl(CDate(Datetext2))
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 6).Value = parttext2.Text
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 7).Value = commentstext2.Text
Worksheets("DW10 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 8).Value = codetext2.Text

confirmupdate.Visible = False

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub confirmupdate_Click()

Dim Rerow As Range

Set Rerow = Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Range("H:H").Find(Codetext, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)


Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 2).Value = Rigtext2.Text
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 4).Value = Serialtext2.Text
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 5).Value = Hourstext2.Text
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 3).Value = CDbl(CDate(Datetext2))
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 6).Value = parttext2.Text
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 7).Value = commentstext2.Text
Worksheets("XUD9 Data").Cells(Rerow.Row, 8).Value = codetext2.Text

confirmupdate.Visible = False

End Sub
```

The error message I get on the XUD9 version is basically Rerow is Nothing, so it obviously can't find the Codetext value to return the row it's looking for, but DW10 works fine with exactly the same code.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I am new to VBA and am self taught (google is your friend) so it could be something very simple.

Comment: the first would result in error too if Codetext is not found. Both need a check if Rerow Is Nothing`

Comment: Which is fair enough but the codetext is automatically created when the data is input. You can only update data after it's been retrieved, which also uses the codetext, and it's retrieving the data with no problem. You have given me an idea of something else I can check though.

Comment: After a quick check there seems to be some issue with the codetext coming through. It's stored as  3613036580043600 but its coming through as 3.6130365800436E+15. (I have the codetext boxes hidden so it wasn't immediately obvious). I'm guessing this would cause my problem. The DW10 codetext are slightly shorter and are coming through as written. how do I make the longer number write to the userform as stored?

Comment: Format the cell as text. Or better yet, precede it with `'`. That is when dumping the `codetext` list into the worksheet. It was not mentioned how exactly you are populating the list on the worksheets so I can only guess.

Comment: Solved it. As the codetext is effectively a random number made from the engine serial number, random four digit number and date I've made it include a letter at the start, this means it has to come through as text. Formatting the cells as text was making all of them go to the E+n format. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code to ensure that what you are looking for appears in the sheets.

```
Option Explicit
Public Rerow As Range

Sub test(ByVal wsName As String, strCodeText As String)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)

        Set Rerow = .Range("H:H").Find(strCodeText, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not Rerow Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 2).Value = Rigtext2.Text
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 4).Value = Serialtext2.Text
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 5).Value = Hourstext2.Text
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 3).Value = CDbl(CDate(Datetext2))
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 6).Value = parttext2.Text
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 7).Value = commentstext2.Text
            .Cells(Rerow.Row, 8).Value = codetext2.Text
        Else
            MsgBox strCodeText & " not appears in column H"
        End If

    End With

    confirmupdate.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub confirmupdate_Click()

    Dim Codetext As String

    Codetext = "Test" 'Change the Codetext to what you are looking for
    Call Module1.test("DW10 Data", Codetext)

    Codetext = "Test2" 'Change the Codetext to what you are looking for
    Call Module1.test("XUD9 Data", Codetext)


End Sub
```